# Using the Google Cloud text to speech API

Tags: google-speech-api

I have very little coding experience and am having a hard time getting started with the Google Cloud text to speech API. I have been referencing the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-protocol). I have completed the initial steps of creating the project, setting up billing, enabling the API, and setting up authentication.

However, I am confused about step 5:

> Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the
>   file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key.
>   This variable only applies to your current shell session, so if you
>   open a new session, set the variable again.

Where exactly do I do this? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the Service account key to your computer on Step#4.

Place the Service account key to a directory on either [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/) or [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/). Then proceed running the following commands:

For Linux/Mac

```
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
```

For Windows

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[PATH]
```